# Using .hdf5 output from Keras library to use with Pytorch

Tags: keras, pytorch, hdf5

Fairly new into machine learning - I have a training script that trains a default model with no weights into a classifier using images as an input, and after the training, it gives an output with an .hdf5 file.

I am aware that the .hdf5 file will contain the model's info and the weights (https://www.tinymind.com/learn/terms/hdf5). But Im trying to find a way to use the output .hdf5 file to a certain script that uses pytorch to classify objects.

There has not been much information how to use this output file format as a model in pytorch after searching.

What would I need to do in order to use this output file as a trained model to be used in torch? I would appreciate it if someone points me in the right direction to get started